# htaccess redirect without the first folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So we have a system in place for dynamic content for clients.

Essentially they have their own domain. But we also store the content on our domain for deployment.

An example:

Our domain: http://domain_one.com/client_domain/home.php
Their domain: http://client_domain.com/home.php

We need to redirect to the client domain which we can place into the htaccess with php.

What we want to do is also redirect the query string. When we add the query string, it redirects the client_domain/home.php to the client_domain.com

Our rewrite url as follows:

```
RewriteRule !^(template_files)($!|/) http://".$domain."/ [R=301,L]
```

This file gets created dynamically via php for those asking about the ".$domain." bit.

Comment: How does the rule look line inside .htaccess file?

Comment: Essentially, we have http://domain.com/client_domain/documents.php, we need to redirect to http://client_domain/documents.php we have already got the client domain via php. We just need to remove it from the redirect and only use the documents.php if that makes sense. Heres the rule: RewriteRule !^(template_files)($!|/) http://www.client_domain.co.za/ [R=301,L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(template_files|web_images)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Ok, that has helped and its working. Now, i have more than 1 folder to exclude, i attempted this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(template_files|web_images)($!|/) [NC] didnt work. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. I would give you points not sure how to give points

Comment: You're welcome, your acceptance is good enough. When you have 15+ reps you can upvote it :)

Comment: One last question haha. We also support products on it. With the products we rewrite the urls. So they are like this: /p/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel - any chance of passing that through as well?

Comment: you mean you want pass whole `/p/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel` instead of `/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel` ?

Comment: Yes, so essentially we just want to exclude the first folder on the redirect and keep the rest. It works great as is.. But does not pass the folders after the first one

Comment: If this rule is in root .htaccess then it will redirect `/p/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel` to `http://domain.com/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel`

Comment: http://www.domain.com/nuskin/p/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel
should redirect to http://nuskin.com/p/114782/galvanic-spa-body-shaping-gel - i really appreciate your help on this. We can work with what we got. Would be a bonus if we can get it like this example here

Comment: But that is already happening with this rule. Try to test in a new browser.